# Append URL Query String

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to rewrite the following url

https://somedomain/index.php?aa=bb&foo=bar&debug=yes&trans_id={integer}&ID={integer}&hfStatus=DONE

using apache rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(qq)-(receipt)\/([1-9]+)\/([1-9]+\/(DONE|PAYMENT_FAIL))$ /index.php?aa=bb&foo=bar&debug=yes&trans_id=$1&ID=$2&hfStatus=$3 [L]
```

but I'm expecting  the url to be
https://somedomain/qq-receipt/928957/928957/DONE

but the resulting url become
https://somedomain/qq-receipt/928957/928957/index.php?aa=bb&foo=bar

Where did I wrong here ?